# Rails Functional Test using Recaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, captcha, recaptcha, functional-testing

My UsersControllerTest currently fails because I use verify_recaptcha in UsersController#create. How can I write my tests such that a known good CAPTCHA response is passed with params[:user]? I am using reCAPTCHA, but I suppose the question would apply to any CAPTCHA implementation.

Here is my UsersController#create

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])    
  if verify_recaptcha(@user) && @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "Account registered!"
    redirect_to new_order_url
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Account not registered!"
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

and here is my functional test

```
test "should create user" do
    assert_difference('User.count') do
      post :create, :user => { :login => "jdoe",
                               :password => "secret", 
                               :password_confirmation => "secret",
                               :first_name => 'john',
                               :last_name => 'doe',
                               :address1 => '123 Main St.',
                               :city => 'Anytown',
                               :state => 'XY',
                               :zip => '99999',
                               :country => 'United States',
                               :email => 'jdoe@example.com' }
    end
end
```

This test fails as follows

```
  4) Failure:
test_should_create_user(UsersControllerTest)
    [(eval):3:in `each_with_index'
     /test/functional/users_controller_test.rb:15:in `test_should_create_user']:
"User.count" didn't change by 1.
<3> expected but was
<2>.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using flexmock or mocha to have all instances of verify_recaptcha return true:

This line in my app made the create test pass without a problem on my app:

```
flexmock(User).new_instances.should_receive(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(true)
```

If you add this line before the "create" action takes place it should work.

Also, I haven't tried out this recaptcha plugin, but this might also be of help for you:
http://www.fromdelhi.com/2006/07/21/rails-captcha-and-testing-using-mock-objects/